# Perl copy scalar to a hash

Tags: perl, hash

I have a hash which I am passing to a subroutine. I pass an empty hash to subroutine as well. I want to copy the contents of the hash to the empty one.

Here's how my code looks:

```
my %emptyHash = ();
my %sourceHash = ();
$sourceHash{'apple'} = 'red';
$sourceHash{'orange'} = 'orange';

mergeHash(\%emptyHash, \%sourceHash);

foreach my $k (keys %emptyHash)
{
  print "key=>". $k. "value=>".$emptyHash{$k}. "\n";
}

sub mergeHash {
  my $emptyHash = shift;
  my $sourceHash = shift;

  $emptyHash = $sourceHash;

}
```

When I print the emptyHash after the merge, I still get an empty hash. Can I not just copy the value of one hash to another this way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$emptyhash` and `$sourcehash` are *references*. When you do `$emptyhash = $sourcehash` you just make the variable `$emptyhash` contain the same reference that `$sourcehash` does.

Instead, you want `%$emptyhash = %$sourcehash`, which acts on the hashes those references *point* to.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want a quick copy or a deep one? A quick copy copies only the top-level scalars of a hash. If the hash contains anonymous arrays or hashes, they will not be copied. Instead, a reference to them is made. That means any changes inside of them will cause the same changes in the copied hash.

Quick copy:

```
%$empty_hash = %$source_hash;
```

Deep copy:

```
use Storable qw( dclone );
$empty_hash = declone( $source_hash );
```

`Storable` is a standard module that comes with Perl. For a list of the standard modules, see [`perldoc perlmodlib`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmodlib.html).

Answer (score 0):

I fixed your code below.

```
my %emptyHash = ();
my %sourceHash = ();
$sourceHash{'apple'} = 'red';
$sourceHash{'orange'} = 'orange';

my $d = mergeHash(\%emptyHash, \%sourceHash);

foreach my $k (keys %$d)
{
  print "key=>". $k. "\tvalue=>". $emptyHash{$k}. "\n";
}

sub mergeHash {
  my $emptyHash = shift;
  my $sourceHash = shift;

  %$emptyHash = %$sourceHash;
  return $emptyHash;
}
```

Comment: $emptyHash in mergeHash function can be only used in mergeHash function. $emptyHash is different if $emptyHash is used in main funcion. So mergeHash funcion needs to return $emptyHash in mergeHash; it needs to assign a value to other variable. Afterward, you can use its variable.

Comment: Furthermore, you can be easy to debug using Data::Dumper module.